# Pandas key error : _get_label_or_level_values raise KeyError(key)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, keyerror

I am having a strange issue with sorting pivot table using pandas.

My Code:

```
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Vulnerability'],values=['IP4','Final Priority Score'] ,aggfunc={'IP4': np.count_nonzero,
                                                                                                           'Final Priority Score': np.mean})
    print(pivot_table.columns.tolist())
    pivot_table.sort_values(by=['IP4'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
['Final Priority Score', 'IP4']
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/i560387/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/vuln_excel.py", line 706, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/i560387/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/vuln_excel.py", line 595, in main
    createPivotTableByVuln(df, severity,ws_vulnerability_history)
  File "/Users/i560387/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/vuln_excel.py", line 444, in createPivotTableByVuln
    pivot_table.sort_values(by=['IP4'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6909, in sort_values
    k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1850, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'IP4'
```

The thing is that it worked previously and suddenly stopped working on new file.

Tried to use different key- same result .

Comment: What's the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: try ```print(df.columns.tolist())``` and check if "IP4" present in the list of column names. Looks like this column was spelled incorrectly / is not present in ```df```

Comment: Please take a look , I printed the output of print(pivot_table.columns.tolist())

Comment: @nivdahan I don't see the output of this

Comment: First line in output: ['Final Priority Score', 'IP4']  @dramarama